# How to call react logger function when using CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, cdn, redux-logger

I'm creating files to learn react myself.
To simplify things I use cdn and everything went flowless till now.
I can't figure out how to provide the redux-logger middleware to my Redux.applymiddleware fn.

What should I replace the /* logger here */ string with ?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>React step by step</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.1/dist/redux.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/redux-thunk@2.1.0/dist/redux-thunk.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/redux-logger@3.0.6/dist/redux-logger.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Open your Dev tool!  (F12)</div> 
    </body>
    
    <script type="text/babel" >

        const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
            return state;
        }
        //const myMiddleware = Redux.applyMiddleware( /* logger here */)

        const store = Redux.createStore( reducer/*, myMiddleware*/ );

        store.dispatch({ type: 'FOO'});

        const currentState = store.getState();

        console.log(currentState)

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: `const store = createStore(reducer, {}, applyMiddleware(logger));` I use this

Comment: I am using cdn, this way applyMiddleware would be undefined, and so would be logger. Your solution works whn you import these variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check `redux-logger`'s [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) bundler config, which is in their GitHub repo: https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger/blob/master/rollup.config.js#L33 - you'll see that they named the module for the UMD bundle as `reduxLogger`. So you should access it as follows:

```
const logger = window.reduxLogger.logger
```

Comment: well done, thanks. It's good you pointed out the link, i didn't really know where to find that info